# Proof that consecutive terms of a sequence are coprime

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, prime-numbers

I've been dealing with the following problem for a while:

> Let $a_n$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{N}$, such that $a_{0} =7, a_{1} =9, a_{n} =5 \cdot a_{n-1}-2 \cdot a_{n-2}$. Prove that $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ are coprime.

I've tried coming up with a general formula for $a_n$ but couldn't. I know that the gcd between $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ should be 1, but how should I prove it? I guess that I could say that there's a prime that divide's both of them and get a contradiction...

So if p divides $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ it must divide their sum:

$5(a_n + a_{n-1}) \equiv 2 (a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}) \mod {p}$

$p$ can't divide both 5 and 2 at the same time unless it's 1. But what can I say about the rest? Is this the best way to go?

Thanks

Comment: Hint:  use induction.

Comment: @lulu how exactly? I've tried by setting my hypothesis to $gcd(a_n, a_{n+1)}=1$ but can't work my way around it.

Comment: Well...say $p\,|\,\gcd(a_n,a_{n-1})$.  Then of course $p\,|\,2a_{n-2}$.  It is easy to see that all the $a_n$ are odd so we must have $p\,|\,a_{n-2}$.  Thus $p\,|\,\gcd(a_{n-2},a_{n-1})$

Comment: @Gio You could try infinite descent, which is almost like induction (it's what induction becomes if you throw in a contrapositive at the right moment). The problem then reads "Let $k\geq1$ be a number such that $\gcd(a_k, a_{k+1})\neq 1$. Show that $\gcd(a_{k-1}, a_k)\neq 1$."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proof by induction.

Step I:  All the $a_n$ are odd.

Pf:  Clearly they start odd, if we assume that $a_{n-1}$ is odd then the recursion instantly implies that $a_n$ is also odd.

Step II.  Assume, inductively,  that $\gcd(a_{n-1},a_{n-2})=1$

Note that this is easily proven for small $n$.

Now suppose that $\gcd(a_n,a_{n-1})>1$ and let $p$ denote a prime which divides that $\gcd$.  We remark that Step I implies that $p$ is odd.

Since $p$ divides both $a_n$ and $a_{n-1}$ we see that $p$ divides $2a_{n-2}$ as $$2a_{n-2}=5a_{n-1}-a_n$$

As $p$ is odd this implies that $p\,|\,a_{n-2}$ thus $p\,|\,\gcd(a_{n-2},a_{n-1})$ in contradiction of the induction hypothesis, and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

Just solving the recurrence:

> Let $a_n$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{N}$, such that $a_{0} =7, a_{1} =9, a_{n} =5 \cdot a_{n-1}-2 \cdot a_{n-2}$.

This is a homogeneous linear recurrence relation with constant coefficionts, so [the usual algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) works.

The characteristic polynomial is
$$
p(t) = t^2 - 5t + 2 
$$
Going for the roots
$$
0 = (t - 5/2)^2 + 2 - 25/4 = (t - 5/2)^2 - 17/4 \iff \\
t = \frac{5 \pm\sqrt{17}}{2}
$$
This gives the general solution
$$
a_n = 
k_1 \left( \frac{5 + \sqrt{17}}{2} \right)^n + 
k_2 \left( \frac{5 - \sqrt{17}}{2} \right)^n
$$
Applying the initial values gives
$$
a_0 = k_1 + k_2 = 7 \\
a_1 = k_1 \frac{5 + \sqrt{17}}{2} + 
k_2 \frac{5 - \sqrt{17}}{2} = 9
$$
and
$$
k_1 = \frac{7 - \sqrt{17}}{2} \\
k_2 = \frac{7 + \sqrt{17}}{2} \\
$$
and we get
$$
a_n = 
\frac{7 - \sqrt{17}}{2} \left( \frac{5 + \sqrt{17}}{2} \right)^n +
\frac{7 + \sqrt{17}}{2} \left( \frac{5 - \sqrt{17}}{2} \right)^n
$$
No idea yet if that form is of any help.

Comment: This helps too, thanks. I didn't know about this algorithm... does it have a particular name?

Comment: I added a link. Sadly I do not know about the history of that subject.